# How would you calculate the X° step of an Exponential Moving Average?

Tags: c++, algorithm, moving-average

I smooth some data using a basic `Exponential Moving Average` [filter](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6678131072419c7):

```
int main ()
{
    double a0 = 0.1;
    double input = 8.0;
    double z = 0.0;

    for(int i=0; i < 200; i++) {
        z += a0 * (input - z);
        std::cout << i  << "° : "<< z << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For some reasons, I'd like to do it every X (=8) steps.
The fact is that as for now, I don't know how to calculate it every 8° input. I still process at every input and "store" only the 8°.

How would you "save CPU" avoid to calculate it on each step? Is there a series where I can just calculate 8° value ahead?

This is the actual [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd7906887323c917) I have (which smooth at each step):

```
int main ()
{
    double a0 = 0.1;
    double input = 8.0;
    double z = 0.0;
    int step = 8;


    for(int i=0; i < 200; i+=8) {
        z += a0 * (input - z);
        std::cout << i  << "° : "<< z << std::endl;

        int j = 1;
        while (j++ < step) {
            z += a0 * (input - z);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid the "7 steps of while" into a unique operation. Is it possible?

Comment: its just a matter of doing the maths, no?

Comment: I would assume the input is changing in the actual use. Is it changing every step - or only every 8:th step (which seems weird)? If it changes every step then your code is about as good as it gets.

Comment: @HansOlsson: yes input will change. But not at every step. Every Y steps (a buffer, which is way bigger than 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an *exponential* moving average function for a reason: the difference `(input - z0)` is an exponentially decreasing function of the number of steps. In fact, after N steps the decrease is `pow(1-a0,N)`.

Now the relevant math is `pow(x,N) == pow(pow(x,8), N/8)`.

Comment: Not at all weird. A 10% decrease per step is indeed a 57% decrease after 8 steps.

Comment: I mean, here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b89b71b7b5cf0999 the 8° value is 0.61258, not 0.430467

Comment: @markzzz: But that is asymptomatically going to a limit of 1. That's why I said that the _difference_ between the current value and the limit is exponentially decreasing.

Comment: @markzzz: If your limit is 1, yes. If your limit is 8, you'd have to multiply the whole thing by 8 of course.

Comment: What if I need to care about starting point? I.e. smoothed vale after 8 step starting at z=0.54?

Comment: @markzzz: Doesn't matter - it's not the starting point or the limit, but the difference between the two which decreases exponentially

Comment: Not sure how I should use It? pow(0.54 - a0,N)?

Comment: I think I've found the "way": `0.54 + (0.8 - 0.54) * (1.0 - pow(1.0 - a0, step))` ;)